# Hardware and software to program AT89S52 chips with linux

Tags: microcontroller, 8051, isp

Seeing that the ATMEL AT89S52 chips are so cheap (8 usd for 5 with free shipping from ebay!), are supposed to have a simple architecture and a lot of documentation available online, I would like to use them to learn microcontrollers at a lower level than the Arduino.

I have already learned how to compile simple programs with sdcc and convert the resulting ihx file to hex with packihx, ready to be loaded into the chip.

I don't understand what hardware and software is needed to transfer the file from my laptop via a usb port. From what I've read avrdude doesn't work for these chips, what should I use instead? Also, what hardware should I buy to do the programming?

Can someone provide a simple guide for a beginner?

Thanks

EDIT: If I understand correctly, the circuit provided by Sandun only converts the RS-232 voltages down to 5V. If this is correct, and since I'll be using a USB port instead of a serial one, can I just use a USB - serial cable which outputs 5V like this [one](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Cables/DS_TTL-232R_CABLES.pdf)? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple ISP Serial programmer and use software like [PonyProg](http://www.lancos.com/prog.html).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is any kit or assembled version of this or a similar board I can buy?

Comment: it's called a ISP programmer. 
If you buying then buy a USB based one.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion? The Atmel AVRISP mkii does not list the chips as supported. The usbtinyisp from adafruit and the usbasp from fischl also don't (I'm not 100% sure about the usbasp). I don't know of any others.

Comment: I'm using that serial adapter that I mentioned above.

Comment: I'm using the serial adapter that I mentioned above. I know it's working with ponyprog + Linux.

Comment: @Martin Vidner please don't make **absurdly trivial** edits to 3 year old questions - it just bumps them to the top of the page for no legitimate reason.